# Can JaxRsController access jax-rs resources that are in my custom grails plugin?

Tags: grails, jax-rs, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 2.2 and the JSR 311 jax-rs plugin.

I've created a custom Grails plugin (call it MyPlugin) using jax-rs resources, and installed it in another Grails application (call it MyApplication), which is also built around jax-rs.

I am having issues reaching any of the MyPlugin resources from MyApplication - it seems like the JaxRsController is not aware of the resources embedded in MyPlugin. I seem to recall reading that it only searches 'MyApplication/grails-app/resources' for jax-rs resources, which would explain it.

Is there a way to make the JaxRsController aware of MyPlugin's jax-rs resources? If not, is there a better approach than installing a jax-rs plugin inside another jax-rs app?

Comment: The plugin seems to get all artefacts by his type (in this case resources type). Maybe it's the load order of the plugins. Add def `loadBefore = ['Jaxrs']` in your plugin descriptor and check your application again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sergio.. turns out I have no idea what was preventing my plugin from working, but when I upped the version number (I literally changed nothing else), it magically worked. Don't ask me how that made a difference because I have no clue..

Comment: Maybe you changed something in your plugin, but your application already had downloaded that version, so it didn't get updated. When you changed the version, your application updated correctly, fixing your problem.